# C# Mongo remove sub document of sub document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I has the following documents in my collection:

```
{
    "Target_Year" : 2017,
    "Target_Month" : 6,
    "Performance" : [ 
        {
            "Report_Day" : 1,
            "SM_Name" : "RACHEL",
            "Total" : [{"SM": "A"},
                       {"SM": "B"}
                      ]
        }, 
    ]
}
```

My Code

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filterMain = builder.Eq("Target_Year", "2017") & builder.Eq("Target_Month", "6");
var filterPerf = builder.Eq("Report_Day", "1");
mongoDB.SuperiorPerformance.FindOneAndUpdate(filterMain, Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.PullFilter("Performance", filterPerf));
```

How can I amend my codes to ONLY REMOVE {"SM": "A"} from Total?

Comment: Update Total after removing {"SM": "A"}

Comment: Can you further elaborate? I can't get it.

Comment: var filterPerf = builder.Eq("Report_Day", "1"), update performance like this    "Performance" : [ 
        {
            "Report_Day" : 1,
            "SM_Name" : "RACHEL",
            "Total" : [  {"SM": "B"}
                      ]
        }, 
    ], Means in c# List, remove Item.

Comment: Has this answer matced your requirement

Comment: @VijayRaheja Your comments do not address the issue but the given answer does. There are two things needed to effect a `$pull` here. 1. You need to include something to match the "outer" array element within the query. 2. The `$pull` statement to construct needs the positional `$` operator to represent the matched index and then needs to point to the correct field to in fact "pull" from. It's not a C# list, it's a MongoDB document in a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **also** match the "outer" array in the query to select, then use the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in the path to [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) in order to address the correct array element:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filterMain = builder.Eq("Target_Year", 2017) & builder.Eq("Target_Month", 6)
   & builder.Eq("Performance.Report_Day", 1);

var filterTotal = builder.Eq("SM", "A");

mongoDB.SuperiorPerformance.FindOneAndUpdate(
  filterMain,
  Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.PullFilter("Performance.$.Total", filterTotal));
```

Works to the be the same as this:

```
.update(
  { "Target_Year": 2017, "Target_Month": 6, "Performance.Report_Day": 1 },
  { "$pull": { "Performance.$.Total": { "SM": "A" } } }
)
```

Run and tested and gives me the result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5951e89738470d375d40ac9e"),
        "Target_Year" : 2017,
        "Target_Month" : 6,
        "Performance" : [
                {
                        "Report_Day" : 1,
                        "SM_Name" : "RACHEL",
                        "Total" : [
                                {
                                        "SM" : "B"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: @CheeMun If you have a new question then please [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you post your new question as clearly as you did with this one, then myself or someone else will be happy to answer.